# Laravel 5.6 Debug no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

ya no se que hacer, no funciona el debug de laravel 5.6.
Logicamente tengo en =true en el archivo .env y en app.php y sigue sin funcionar probe tambien con los comandos php artisan config:cache y nada, si hago un dd(config('app.debug')); el resultado es true, en el enviroment lo tengo en local pero sigue sin mostrarme los errores solo me sale el mensaje "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." su ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

intente utilizar el siguiente codigo, en routes/web.php en la parte de servidor compartidos, en caso de que no tenga disponible la consola de comando

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

   Artisan::call('cache:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:cache');
   Artisan::call('view:clear');

   return "Cleared!";

});
```

Tenga en cuenta que cualquier cambio en la configuración no tendrá ningún efecto una vez que lo almacene en caché. Para actualizar la configuración se debe ejecuta el comando de limpieza

fuente de la información 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server